# C how to input values separated by spaces(Battleship game)

Tags: c

So, I have to this this battleship game in 'c' where I have one function which when called asks for input of the size of a board, 2 lines of numbers (it's not really important what they do for now) and a board that represents the battleship board. So the input looks like this:

> c
>
> 10 10
>
> 3 1 3 1 2 2 3 1 1 3
>
> 2 2 0 2 2 2 2 3 4 1
>
> ..........
>
> ..........
>
> ..........
>
> ..........
>
> ...~......
>
> <.........
>
> ...~...^.~
>
> ..........
>
> ..........
>
> ..........

**THE IMPORTANT PART**

I need help, because I cant take numbers or characters individually to store in separate variables. I tried using scanf() but it doesn't work because of the spaces.  How could I do this?  (i'm looking for possibly the simplest way of doing it)

This is along the lines of what I have:

```
void c(){
int a, c;
scanf("%d %d", &alt, &comp);
/*alt and comp are external. these will hold the first two numbers */

for(a=0; a< alt; a++){
    scanf("%d", &s[0][a]); 
}
for(c=0; c < comp; c++){
    scanf("%d", &s[1][c]);
} /* these two fors are supposed to get the first two rows of numbers to an external array */

for(a=0; a < alt, a++){
    for(c=0; c < comp; c++){
        scanf("%c", &tab[a][c]);
    }
}/* this is supposed to get the board to 'tab' (external) */
}
```

Comment: Where's the code that doesn't work?

Comment: This line `scanf("%d %d", &alt, &comp);` should work just fine for getting something like `10 10`.

Comment: Maybe you need this: `scanf("%d %d*", &alt, &comp);` as you may have pressed Enter to go on inputting.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding a space into the scanf like this: `scanf("%d ", &s[1][c]);` to consume the spaces, but then you will need to special case the last number on the line since it won't have a trailing space.

Instead I would read in the whole line of numbers and use [strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strtok/) to split the line on the spaces.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char[100] line;
char *number;
int i;

i = 0;
gets(line);
number = strtok (line, " ");
while(number != NULL;) {
    s[0][i] = atoi(number);
    number = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i += 1;
}

i = 0;
gets(line);
number = strtok (line, " ");
while(number != NULL;) {
    s[1][i] = atoi(number);
    number = strtok(NULL, " ");
    i += 1;
}
```